# Image onload not called when setting source

Tags: javascript, image, svg, onload

Why is the onload event never fired in following snippet?

```
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function() {
  alert("ok");
}
var svg = '<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>'

img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(svg);
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/venmmn3b/1/

Answer (score 5):

Because it is NOT ok -

- missing quote in your svg string
- the image triggers the error and not the load handler

```js
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function() {
  console.log("ok");
}
img.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("Not ok",e);
}
var svg = '<svg></svg>';
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(svg);
```

I even tried to add valid svg:

```js
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function() {
  console.log("ok");
}
img.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("Not ok",e);
}
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><text font-size="68" font-weight="bold" font-family="DejaVu Sans" y="52" x="4" transform="scale(.8,1.7)"><tspan fill="#248">W3</tspan>C</text> <path fill="none" stroke="#490" stroke-width="12" d="m138 66 20 20 30-74"/></svg>';
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Any thoughts why the svg image isn't valid?

Comment: No. And there is not even a reason to use BTOA https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `xmlns` and `version` attributes to the svg.

Example: `<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Terje answer I managed to make it work.
I still had to create a blob and an object URL as stated in [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/draw-an-svg-to-canvas-and-download-it-as-image-in-javascript-f7f7713cf81f).

```js
    // SVG Containing version and xmlns attributes as Terje stated
    const my_svg = `<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>`; 
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    const blob = new Blob([my_svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' })
    const URLSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    img.onload = function () {
      console.log('Image Loaded')
    }

    img.src = URLSrc;
```

Comment: can you share working snippet. For bloburl IMG onload is not firing

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote in the line

```
 var svg = '<svg></svg>';.
```

and also it's working when i keep image source as "http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg". So i think there is something wrong with your image only.

Comment: Fixed the typo.